# How to add SignalR request Headers on .net client side

Tags: .net-core, signalr

I have server side Hub with the following code:

```
        private string GetUserPhoneFromContext()
        {
            var httpCtx = Context.GetHttpContext();
            return httpCtx.Request.Headers["userPhone"].ToString();
        }
```

Mention above code I can't change it works on prod with flutter clients.
I am developing blazor wasm client side and on client side I want to add headers as follow:

```
 hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
                .WithUrl($"{Uri}?userPhone={Phone}", options =>
                {
                    options.Headers.Add("userPhone", Phone);                    
                })
                .WithAutomaticReconnect()
                .Build();
```

But nor via options.Header.Add() neither via adding query string parameter I can't read header on the server side via GetUserPhoneFromContext method, I always get empty string instead of added on client userPhone header. Not clearly understand why it works with flutter clients but does not work with .net blazor wasm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find out the root. The Blazor WASM SignalR implemetation is a wrapper around JS implementation that does not support Headers. If you need additional data use QueryString

see https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/18694 for more